# Azure DevOps sharing parts of repo

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-devops

I have in my repo 6 projects that I would like to devide into 6 teams in which each team has a two smaller teams that one works on backend and the other on frontend. Is it possible to give access only to the certain project to certain developers/groups? Do anybody know a method to work with something like this?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible because of how git works, you'd need to separate those into different repos and grant access to those (you can be granular up to a repo level).